# how to check package first time run install from Microsoft store

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, store

i create a simple application in which i want to show a quick tour on first time run. 
so is any event or other things which indicates me that app is executing first time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use Settings. You can find this object in Properties of your solution.

[image]

There you can add an setting of type bool and set it to true.

[image]

From there it is a simple property access but don't forget to update the setting to false and save those settings.

```
if (Test.Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun)
{
    // Run tutorial
    Test.Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
    Test.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: thanks for help i have one question. in window store application is any location where we can store a hidden file. if user uninstall application then that file would not delete. and next time if user install again then we can access that